# Формирование запроса JSON найти ошибку

Tags: php, json, api

отправляю запрос в Яндекс Директ на создание нового клиента, на сайте документации есть пример запроса который мне нужен, я фактически его копирую от туда, но где то все же ошибка у меня, помогите найти пожалуйста:

Код примера формирования запроса от Яндекса (JSON):

```
{   "method": "add",   "params": { /* params */
      "Login": (string), /* required */
      "FirstName": (string), /* required */
      "LastName": (string), /* required */
      "Currency": ( "RUB" | "BYN" | "CHF" | "EUR" | "KZT" | "TRY" | "UAH" | "USD" ), /* required */
      "Grants": [{  /* GrantItem */
        "Privilege": ( "EDIT_CAMPAIGNS" | "IMPORT_XLS" | "TRANSFER_MONEY" ), /* required */
        "Value": ( "YES" | "NO" ) /* required */
      }, ... ],
      "Notification": {  /* NotificationAdd */
        "Lang": ( "RU" | "UK" | "EN" | "TR" ), /* required */
        "Email": (string), /* required */
        "EmailSubscriptions": [{  /* EmailSubscriptionItem */
          "Option": ( "RECEIVE_RECOMMENDATIONS" | "TRACK_MANAGED_CAMPAIGNS" | "TRACK_POSITION_CHANGES" ), /* required */
          "Value": ( "YES" | "NO" ) /* required */
        }, ... ] /* required */
      }, /* required */
      "Settings": [{  /* ClientSettingAddItem */
        "Option": ( "CORRECT_TYPOS_AUTOMATICALLY" | "DISPLAY_STORE_RATING" ), /* required */
        "Value": ( "YES" | "NO" ) /* required */
      }, ... ]   } }
```

Мой код формирования запроса:

```
public static function addClientAgency($user_id): object
    {
        //--- Входные данные ----------------------------------------------------//
        // Адрес сервиса для отправки JSON-запросов (регистрозависимый)
        $config = config::get_config();
        $directToken = $config['dirtoken'];
        $user_info = login::genYaLogin($user_id);

        $url = 'https://api-sandbox.direct.yandex.com/json/v5/agencyclients';
        //--- Подготовка и выполнение запроса -----------------------------------//
        // Установка HTTP-заголовков запроса
        $headers = array(
            "Authorization: Bearer $directToken",                    // OAuth-токен. Использование слова Bearer обязательно
            "Accept-Language: ru",                             // Язык ответных сообщений
            "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"    // Тип данных и кодировка запроса
        );
        // Параметры запроса к серверу API Директа
        $params = array(
            'method' => 'add',                                 // Используемый метод сервиса AgencyClients
            'params' => array(
                'Login' => $user_info['login'],
                'FirstName' => $user_info['first'],
                'LastName' => $user_info['last'],
                'Currency' => 'RUB',
                'Grants' => array(
                    'Privilege' => 'EDIT_CAMPAIGNS',
                    'Value' => 'YES'
                ),
                'Notification' => array(
                    'Lang' => 'RU',
                    'Email' => $user_info['email'],
                    'EmailSubscriptions' => array(
                        'Option' => 'TRACK_MANAGED_CAMPAIGNS',
                        'Value' => 'YES'
                    )
                ),
                'Settings' => array(
                    'Option' => 'CORRECT_TYPOS_AUTOMATICALLY',
                    'Value' => 'YES'
                )
            )
        );
        // Преобразование входных параметров запроса в формат JSON
        $body = json_encode($params, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        // Создание контекста потока: установка HTTP-заголовков и тела запроса
        $streamOptions = stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'header' => $headers,
                'content' => $body
            )
        ));
        // Выполнение запроса, получение результата
        $result = file_get_contents($url, 0, $streamOptions);
        $result = json_decode($result);
        if ($result === false) {
            echo "Ошибка выполнения запроса!";
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

В общем у меня получается вот такой json:

```
{
    "method": "add",
    "params": {
        "Login": "dir-m-arigon-l",
        "FirstName": "Леонид",
        "LastName": "Басов",
        "Currency": "RUB",
        "Grants": {
            "Privilege": "EDIT_CAMPAIGNS",
            "Value": "YES"
        },
        "Notification": {
            "Lang": "RU",
            "Email": "arigon-l@yandex.ru",
            "EmailSubscriptions": [
                {
                    "Option": "TRACK_MANAGED_CAMPAIGNS",
                    "Value": "YES"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Settings": {
            "Option": "CORRECT_TYPOS_AUTOMATICALLY",
            "Value": "YES"
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка возникает при обработке поля Notification, ругается что это не массив, хотя вроде передаю данные в виде массива по примеру который использую на других методах. Сама ошибка:

> stdClass Object ( [error] => stdClass Object ( [request_id] =>
> 2596958714906712827 [error_code] => 8000 [error_detail] =>
> Notification.EmailSubscriptions должен содержать массив [error_string]
> => Некорректный запрос ) )

Comment: Приведите пример json, на который ругается

Comment: В примере `EmailSubscriptions` содержит массив объектов, у вас же это сразу объект(после перехода в json). Оберните содержимое `EmailSubscriptions` в ещё один массив

Comment: Sheridan - добавил пример json, Ein -  вот так: 'EmailSubscriptions' => array(array( 'Option' => 'TRACK_MANAGED_CAMPAIGNS','Value' => 'YES'))), ? сделал все равно такая же ошибка( Спасибо что помогаете, извините за нубство .. =(

Comment: Похоже на правду. Но в примере всё равно не вижу что бы `EmailSubscriptions` стал массивом. Ошибка точно такая же?

Comment: Все получилось, вы правы! нужно было еще раз обернуть в массив все элементы подобного типа! Большое спасибо и поклон в японском стиле!

Comment: @Ein Оформите, пожалуйста, ответом ваш комментарий, он оказался верным :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В примере `EmailSubscriptions`, `Settings` и `Grants` являются массивами объектов. Соответсвенно, нужно просто дополнительно обернуть содержимое этих элементов в массив:

```
    $params = array(
        'method' => 'add',
        'params' => array(
            'Login' => $user_info['login'],
            'FirstName' => $user_info['first'],
            'LastName' => $user_info['last'],
            'Currency' => 'RUB',
            'Grants' => array( // <------------
                array(
                    'Privilege' => 'EDIT_CAMPAIGNS',
                    'Value' => 'YES'
                )
            ) ,
            'Notification' => array( // <------------
                array(
                    'Lang' => 'RU',
                    'Email' => $user_info['email'],
                    'EmailSubscriptions' => array(
                        'Option' => 'TRACK_MANAGED_CAMPAIGNS',
                        'Value' => 'YES'
                    )
                )
            ) ,
            'Settings' => array( // <------------
                array(
                    'Option' => 'CORRECT_TYPOS_AUTOMATICALLY',
                    'Value' => 'YES'
                )
            )
        )
    );
```